# prevent modal from opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm working on a Fullcalendar project.
This is how I open my modal to edit Events:

```
eventClick: function eventClick(event) {
  $('#editNewEvent').modal('show');
  //function....
}
```

and this is how I delete them:

```
eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {

  if (view.name == 'listDay') {
    element.find(".fc-list-item-time").append("<span class='closeon'>X</span>");                            
  } else {
    element.find(".fc-content").prepend("<span class='closeon'>X</span>");
  }

  element.find(".closeon").on('click', function() {
    $('#editNewEvent').modal('hide');

    if(event.nomeUtente == $("#nomeUtente").data('value')){
      var deleteMsg = confirm("Vuoi davvero eliminare " + event.title + "?");
      if (deleteMsg == true) {                      
        $.ajax({
          url: 'eventi/deleteEvent.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data:  {_id: event.idAssenza, nomeUtente: event.nomeUtente}
        })

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
      }
    }
    else {
      alert('Non puoi eliminare questo evento!');
    } 
  });
}
```

When I trigger the `else` part, after the `alert`, it appared the modal to edit events. Is there a way not to trigger the editEvents modal in this case?

I've already tried to add: `$('#editNewEvent').modal('hide');`
but It show up anyways

---

This is an event from my calendar: [image: event]

Basically when I click on the event normally, it appared the modal to edit the event.

When I click on the *X*, at first my code check if the current $_SESSION[user] is the same person as the one that create the event (`if(event.nomeUtente == $("#nomeUtente").data('value')){`). If it's the same than it appared the confirm alert and proceded to delete the event; if not it appared an alert where it's says *"'Non puoi eliminare questo evento!'"* and my problem is in this last case; because after this alert it appared the modal to edit the events and I dont want that.

Comment: It's unclear, is the second piece of code part of the `eventClick` function? Or part of something else? Please make sure you demonstrate a [mre] of the problem. We can't quite be sure of the order / flow of code from what is provided now.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed a part of the code. I'm gonna update it

Comment: The deleted function is in my eventRender part

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that when it goes into  the `if(event.nomeUtente == $("#nomeUtente").data('value')){` section the modal stays hidden, but if it goes into the `else {
      alert('Non puoi eliminare questo evento!');
    } ` then the modal appears?

Comment: I'm gonna update the question and explain it better

Comment: I hope I was clear enough, sorry if not :(

Comment: But also, to asnwered your question: **Yes**, and I dont want that. I want the modal to stay always hidden. In any case

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to make much sense since `$('#editNewEvent').modal('hide');` is outside both the `if` and the `else`. It would be interesting perhaps to know in what order the events occur - specifically the eventClick and the click on the ".closeon" button. Which is first? You can add some console.log commands to each one, to find out. It might make some difference, especially as the alert() will suspend execution of the "closeon" click event temporarily.

Comment: I might sound stupid, but I totally forgot I put a modal.Hide before the if (I'm debugging this code so kinda full of different stuff)

Comment: I'm gonna try to see with some console.log

Comment: @ADyson there is like a very short time between the two of them, but ".closeon" is the first one to show up

Comment: Ok well that means that `$('#editNewEvent').modal('hide');` will run first, and then `$('#editNewEvent').modal('show');` will run second. That would explain your problem.